# ¿Como instalar odoo en Mac?

Tags: macos, odoo

He buscado por todos lados como instalar `Odoo` en una **mac** , se supone que lo instalé pero al poner `localhost:8069` el puerto donde se supone está levantado el servicio no me carga nada, pruebo a parar el servidor pero dice

> comand not found

Todo esto lo hice a nivel de consola. Alguien sabe si existe un `instalador.dmg` directo del `odoo`? , o que me recomiendan hacer?

Comment: Que versión de `Odoo` estás intentado instalar ?

Comment: Odoo12 , la ultima version

Comment: Me parece que deberías incluir mas datos como la versión del sistema operativo de tu Mac.

Comment: localhost:8069 debes ponerlo en el navegador no en la consola.